# Is it possible to make an auto updating website

Tags: 22.04, automation

I am making a website and I want it to automatically upload and update the code in the server when I make changes on my computer. I am using the latest ubuntu server I also have the vscode if there are any exertions in there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook ?

Comment: I'm not using git

Comment: Just a heads-up that there are now 4-votes to close (including mine) this for *"Needs details or clarity"*.  You don't mention much about your tools or workflow.  If you are just looking for recommendations on tools or workflow, then that would probably be far too broad a question (which should be closed as *"Needs more focus"*).  What you seem to be asking about is really CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) strategies.  That's just too "open-ended" a question for our Q&A style here.  I'd recommend looking up some introductions to Continuous Integration and go from there.

Comment: Other than that, I guess it would be possible to use shell scripting. I guess `ssh` and `rsync` would be relevant here. Here are some ideas about how to overcome the challenge of providing the server password automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3299951 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111526 Then you can just run the script in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As Levente has pointed out, using Git would be smart for a number of reasons (ie. versioning, staging before production, etc.), but if you can't use it for whatever reason, check this out:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Basically you open a VS Code window on your machine but use the file system on the remote server and edit the files in real time.

I need to do my due diligence and tell you that this is **not** a good idea for production use. If the files are static, consider using the Live Server extension which can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

Good luck!